# Is there a Virial theorem in General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, lagrangian-formalism, virial-theorem

I know that in Newtonian mechanics one can derive the virial theorem for $N$ gravitating particles

\begin{equation}
2\langle T\rangle=-\langle U\rangle 
\end{equation}

where $T$ is the kinetic energy of said particles and $U$ is their Newtonian gravitational energy. This can also be generalized to special relativity without too many problems. Now, let’s say we have an action principle

\begin{equation}
S=\int d^4x \big( L_{matter}+L_{EH}\big)
\end{equation}

Where $L_{matter}$ is the Lagrangian density for the matter distribution and $L_{EH}$ is the Einstein-Hilbert action for General Relativity.

**Is there a derivation of a [virial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem) where we get some average of the energy momentum tensor on one side and some notion of gravitational energy coming from the metric tensor on the other side?**

I tried searching for this but its unclear that it exists when treating gravity in full general relativity. Any explanations would be great, thanks!

Comment: Some papers that might be interesting: https://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1973ApJ...182..335B, https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/11/2/015/meta. One thing to keep in mind is that you will probably only be able to prove a theorem under assumptions about the asymptotic geometry, since it's only possible to define a conserved energy for special asymptotic conditions.